# Is the purpose of the 'Your Communities' 'Email address' account setting to specify where notifications are to be sent?

Tags: support, email, email-settings-page

I am a novice user trying to better understand the available account settings. If there is existing documentation that describes each field, please point me to its location.

In **Account > Settings > EMAIL SETTINGS > Edit email settings > Your Communities** is a field called **Email address**. Does this field specify where all email notifications involving the account are to be sent?

[image]

Comment: Yes; note the text on the top right corner that states that "These settings affect" all sites on which you have a profile.

Comment: The processed screenshot looks very cool (and is very *functional* as well). This should set the new standard. How did you do it?

Comment: @Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog, Okay thanks. This is different than other forums I use where the email you sign up with is the email used for notifications.

Comment: @ This_is_NOT_a_forum, I use an app called Snagit by TechSmith. The app allows me to easily capture screenshots, and has tools that make it easy to markup, crop, and add shadows to any capture.